# SimpleNLG - How to get the plural of a noun?

Tags: java, nlp, nlg, simplenlg

I'm using `SimpleNLG 4.4.2` to get plural form for a noun:

```
final XMLLexicon xmlLexicon = new XMLLexicon();
final WordElement word = xmlLexicon.getWord("apple", LexicalCategory.NOUN);
System.out.println(word);
System.out.println(word.getFeature(LexicalFeature.PLURAL));
```

However even for this simple example, `getFeature` returns `null` instead of `apples`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it return `null` for a noun with irregular plural, like `ox` or `automaton`? Also, have you seen [the caveat at the bottom of this page](https://code.google.com/p/simplenlg/wiki/Section4)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for making me aware of this library! Based on the comment from biziclop, I came up with this solution:

```
final XMLLexicon xmlLexicon = new XMLLexicon();
final WordElement word = xmlLexicon.getWord("apple", LexicalCategory.NOUN);
final InflectedWordElement pluralWord = new InflectedWordElement(word);
pluralWord.setPlural(true);
final Realiser realiser = new Realiser(xmlLexicon);
System.out.println(realiser.realise(pluralWord));
```

which outputs:

```
apples
```